# how to draw the transistor level schematic a 3-port SRAM

Tags: sram

I have been trying to look up 3 port SRAM cell (2 reads and 1 write) everywhere, but I can't find anything about it. Does anyone know of any sources where I can look for how one might be implemented using logic gates or transistor level schematics?

Comment: For a single cell? What do you think the difference should be, compared to a 1 read/1 write, or a 25 read/1 write?

Comment: yeah for a single cell. I don't think there is too much of a difference, but it is for a HW

Comment: Say you have a single sram cell 1 read/1 write. What prevents you from bringing its output to multiple places just by splitting the wire?

Comment: 2 read ports maybe?  Try starting here and use the "see Also" links too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_cell_(computing)

Comment: @dim: Obviously, this cell is going to be used in an array to build a much larger memory. The "word select" for each port (the output of the port address decoder) needs to be part of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really unclear, but if someone asked me to draw a 3-port SRAM cell, it would go something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLgjTT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>